# Submit a form using jquery onSubmit of first form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two forms in a jsp. I want to submit the second form using jquery .submit function.

form1:

```
<form name="form1" id="form" action="\saveUser">
   user info'
</form>
```

form2:

```
<form name="form2" action="https://api/saveUser">

</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
  // do something
  document.form2.submit();
}
```

But the second form is not submitting. Can anyone please suggest a better working solution here.

Comment: @APAD1 the first form id is form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an ID to the second form and then fire `.submit()` on submit of the first form:

```js
$('#form').submit(function() {
  // do something
  $('#form2').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" id="form" action="\saveUser">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<form name="form2" id="form2" action="https://api/saveUser">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If you want to submit both forms with a single button, it would probably be better to do it like this:

```js
$('#submit-forms').click(function() {
  // do something
  $('#form1').submit();
  $('#form2').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" id="form" action="\saveUser">
  <input type="text" />
</form>

<form name="form2" id="form2" action="https://api/saveUser">
  <input type="text" />
</form>

<button id="submit-forms">Submit</button>
```

Comment: That worked thanks. But i dont know why the document.form2.submit is not working.

Comment: But there is an issue happening. Only the second form is submitted and redirected to the resultant page. But the first form is stopped from being submitted. Can you please let me know how can i submit the first form as well after submitting the second form.

Comment: `document.form2` is not a valid selector, that's why it wasn't working. Both of these forms will be submitted with the above code, there's probably an issue with your action.

Comment: Updated answer in case you are wanting to submit both forms with the same button.